# `browser.storage.local` in firefox gets cleared on browser restart

Tags: firefox, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-webextensions

My usage of the local storage API is very minimal.

```
var storedStats = browser.storage.local.get();

results = ....

browser.storage.local.set(results);
```

The code works perfectly wrt storing and retrieving data but when I restart my browser, the storage is cleared and I lose all the data stored. Am I missing something? The documentation does not mention such behavior.

Comment: Assuming you don't have some cleaner utility it's either because a) your extension is installed as a temporary, in which case its storage isn't persisted by default, or b) your code is clearing the storage elsewhere.

Comment: @wOxxOm It's a live add-on so 1 is not possible. I'm assuming it is one of my many privacy related add-ons which are cleaning it up.

Comment: I am also seeing this exact issue. Did you ever find a solution? Every-time I restart the browser, my ext storage gets completely cleared out of local. Makes no sense.

Comment: Nope. No luck with this.